# Trying to do contains within DataItem.Eval() during ListView

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding

How would I handle a contains type string evaluation when using DataItem.Eval(item, property) in client side template?

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Employee.FullName")).Contains("Unknown Employee") ? "Contractor": DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Employee.FullName") %>
```

Do not know why I am having an issue finding the solution. I need to use contains, because the string value contains a lot of \n and \t elements. So just an expression such as

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Employee.FullName").Equals("Unknown Employee") ? "Contractor": DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Employee.FullName") %>
```

returns false.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, nevermind. Found out right after I posted it.

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Employee.FullName").ToString().Contains("Unkown Employee") ? "Contractor": DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Employee.FullName") %>
```

Thanks everyone though.